# Как сформировать модель что б обращаться через свойства а не масcивы. С#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, model

Хочу сформировать модель таким образом что б при возвращение на клиент я обращался через точку и свойство а не через номер в массиве. Пример

Есть ряд моделей.

```
public class InstrumentEntity
{
    public string Symbol { get; set; }

    public Indicators Values { get; set; }
}

public class Indicators
{
    public double LastPrice { get; set; }

    public double Change { get; set; }

    public string PerChange { get; set; }
}
```

И вот я заполняю модель

```
List<InstrumentEntity> stocks = new List<InstrumentEntity>();
Indicators indicators = new Indicators()
            {
                LastPrice = 95,
                Change = 0,35,
                PerChange = %0,12
            };

            InstrumentEntity aa= new InstrumentEntity();
            aa.Symbol = "AA";
            aa.Values = indicators;

            stocks.Add(aa);
```

И снова тоже самое

```
Indicators indicators = new Indicators()
            {
                LastPrice = 95,
                Change = 0,35,
                PerChange = %0,12
            };

            InstrumentEntity bac = new InstrumentEntity();
            bac.Symbol = "bac";
            bac.Values = indicators;

            stocks.Add(bac);
```

И так 6 раз к примеру.

Теперь я это дружно запаковал в джейсон и отправил на фронт. На фронте у меня это буде в виде массива

`result[0].symbol` вот так. Каким образом сформировать что б начиная с первого свойства я обращался через symbol? Ведь там всюду одинаковые модели.

Comment: "ачиная с первого свойства я обращался через symbol" - ??

Comment: ну сейчас там лист моделей и в итоге я имею 6 элементов и обращаюсь вот так `var name1 = result[0].symbol, var name2 = result[1].symbol,` А нужно сразу вот так `var name1 = result.symbol` при этом сохранить множественность элементов в json который попадет на фронт

Comment: Я ничего не понял. Хотите - минус поставлю?

Comment: Я неправильно об'яснил...сейчас исправлю

Comment: ну сейчас там лист моделей и в итоге я имею 6 элементов и обращаюсь вот так `var price1 = result[0].values.LastPrice, var price2 = result[1].values.LastPrice,` А нужно сразу вот так `var price1 = result.aa.values.lastprice` при этом сохранить множественность элементов в json который попадет на фронт. 'AA' это названием одного из элементов в листе. Что б я обращался как нас скрине, через свойства к нужному элементу https://static.goanywhere.com/images/tutorials/read-json/ExampleArray.png т.е. что в result был не массив а список элементов с именем что записано в свойство `symbol`

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте в вопрос JSON, который получается сейчас, и как Вы к нему обращаетесь. А также - как Вы хотите к нему обращаться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кажется, я догадался, чего Вы хотите.

Используйте `Dictionary<string, ...>` вместо `List<...>`.

Comment: Да, все верно, спасибо, помогло